# Finding the class of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to reach the class of the clicked button so I can have a generic event which fades out all elements of the generic class "`gen`" except the elements which belongs to the clicked button elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("div .gen").not($(this).class).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

It's currently fading out all elements of class `gen` while I want to keep the class of the clicked button visible.

HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

        <li class="active" class="all"><a href="#shop">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#showcase" class="tuning">Tuning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#help" class="drifting">Drifting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#my account" class="video">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cart" class="auto">Auto Shows </a></li>
        <li><a href="#cart" class="memes">Memes </a></li>
        <li><a href="#cart" class="muscle">Muscle Cars </a></li>
      </ul>
```

Where I want to click the `<a>` element and keep the items within the `<a>` same class visible.

Comment: Why not `.not($(this))`?

Comment: @j08691: why the unnecessary call to jQuery, and not `$("div .gen").not(this)`?

Comment: `this` will refer to `document` fyi

Comment: @DavidThomas - Just using what the OP used minus `.class`. No reason he couldn't use plain `this`, although I wouldn't call it unnecessary.

Comment: i have a mini nav with multiple items which in any of them is click it will hide all elements except the elements in same class as the clicked item and i dont want to have redundant functions for each click event ... currently the fading out is working fine except i cant seem to deselect the elements within the same class as the clicked item so i need to deselect the elements class

Comment: Could you post HTML with your question, then we can stop guessing your intent and try answering the question.

Comment: Do you have any duplicated classes? As in are there ever going to be more than one element in the set with `class="auto"`?

Comment: You have no elements with the `gen` class in your posted HTML. Could you verify that it's the right HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a more explicit way: Add an attribute or an extra class once the element clicked, to mark its status. And then select all except this attribute.

```
$('button.gen').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('clicked', true);
  $("button.gen").not("[clicked='true']").fadeOut(1000);
});
```